# Confusing algebraic solution...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi everyone I'm a bit confused how they got that final value of M. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: is this the problem solving the given equation for $M$?

Comment: Yeah I just don't get how they rearranged m to the M on the right.

Comment: Bring the term containing $Me^t$ to the left side of the equal sign. You then get $M+Me^t$ When you factor out M you get $1+e^t$ that then ends up in the denominator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$M=e^t-e^tM$$
$$\implies M+Me^t=e^t$$
$$\implies M(1+e^t)=e^t$$
$$\implies M={e^t\over1+e^t}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{M}{1-M} = e^t \Rightarrow M = e^t(1-M) = e^t - e^t  M
$$

So we have
$$
M + e^t M = e^t \Rightarrow M(1 + e^t) = e^t
$$
So finally

$$
M = \frac{e^t}{1+e^t}
$$